# Why didn't they use the definite article before these words in this paragraph?

Tags: articles, definite-article, zero-article

Last night, I was reading this article:

[The article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40430-018-1271-9)

Ok, probably you cannot download the paper then I toke a screenshot and uploaded it here for you:

[image: image1]

Please read this paragraph(Highlighted in the above screenshot):

> Park et al. [3] investigated **sonic nozzles** that are applied to **gas flow rate measurements** and determined that the critical pressure ratio is highly dependent on the Reynolds number rather than **area ratio**, especially in the cases with **low flow velocity**. **Variation** of **discharge coefficients** for **sonic nozzles** with **flow geometry** and **Reynolds number** was reported by Paik et al. [4], who determined higher discharge coefficients with increase of **mass flow rate**. Spotts et al. [5] performed a CFD study of the compressible flow through convergent–conical nozzles to investigate the effect of the nozzle pressure ratio and **nozzle angle** on the nozzle performance. They confirmed that for smaller nozzle angles, the discharge coefficient increases and the choked nozzle pressure ratio will be reduced.

Why didn't the bold words or phrases get any definite article "the"?
Totally some parts of this paragraph is odd. e.g. There are two "Reynolds number" and the first one has got a definite article but the last one didn't get. Is it okay?

Answer (score 2):

The author *could* have used the definite article with **the sonic nozzles** since the reference is to specific nozzles (i.e. those "that are applied to gas flow measurements").  But the author chose to present those nozzles generically using the plural, referring to a type of nozzle,  and then rely upon the *that*-clause to do the specifying.

**gas flow rate measurements**, another plural, refers generically to a kind of measurement, not to specific *instances* of measuring.

**area ratio** is again a generality, area ratio *as factor*, rather than a specific set of area ratios.

**low flow velocity** is again a generality, that kind of velocity *as  factor*, rather than actual *instances* of low flow velocities.

> **Speed** is a significant factor when shopping for a striker.

Comment: How about Reynolds number?

Comment: That's a term of art, here used as a *category* of information. *Your medical record shows height, weight, and age.*

Comment: Other bold phrases? e.g. Variation, discharge coefficients, flow geometry,...

Comment: @Roh: Can you not extrapolate from the explanation already provided to you? Or do you prefer to be spoon-fed?